# What is the probability that A will answer correctly d questions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that 2 students A and B are taking tests. A needs to answer a questions, while B needs to answer b questions. All questions and performances are independent. Suppose A and B have a rate of accuracy 0 < p < 1 for each question. Conditioning on that A and B answer correctly c questions in total, what is the probability that A answers correctly d questions? What kind of distribution is this?

If someone could give me a starting point it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $a$ and $b$ are irrelevant. Also, do $A$ and $B$ have the same probability of answering a question correctly? Your question could have been clearer. One more thing: What have you tried? Even if you've attempted something that hasn't worked, it's good to say that.

Comment: yes A and B have the same probability. I just dont even know which distribution to use right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a slightly different approach to solve this problem. The sample space imposed by the condition that there are $c$ correct answers  among a total of $a+b $ answers is given by $\binom{a+b}{c}$, i.e. the number of ways in which $c$ successes  can be distributed among a total of $a+b $ trials. This sample space corresponds to a probability $\binom{a+b}{c} \, p^c \,(1-p)^{a+b-c} $.

Working within this sample space, if we want to know the probability that the first student gives exactly $d $ correct answers, we have to count - among the total $\binom{a+b}{c}$ possible distributions of the $c$ correct answers -   how many of these distributions have $d$ successes among the $a$ answers given by that student (and consequently also $c-d$ successes among the $b$ answers given by the second student).

To count the number  of these "valid" distributions, we can note that the $d $ correct answers can be distributed in $\binom{a}{d} $ ways among the $a$ answers given by the first student. Similarly, the remaining $c-d$ correct answers can be distributed in $\binom {b}{c-d}$ ways among the $b$ answers given by the second student. This leads to a total of $\binom {a}{d} \binom{b}{c-d}$ valid distributions. Dividing this number by the total number of possible distributions, we get that the searched probability is

$$\displaystyle \frac {\binom{a}{d} \binom{b}{c-d}
 }{ \binom{a+b}{c} } $$

Note that this probability does not depend on $p$. We calculated it as the ratio between valid and total possible configurations, but we could also have obtained it as the ratio between the probability of valid distribution and the "total" probability corrisponding to our sample space. In this case, there would have been an identical additional term in the fraction - that is to say, $p^c \,(1-p)^{a+b-c} $ - which would have been canceled out, resulting in the same formula given above.

For example, let us hypothesize that the first and second student give $a=6$ and $b=4$ answers, respectively. Under the condition that $c=7$ among these are correct, our sample space is given by a total of $\binom{10}{7}=120$ possible distributions. Let us hypothesize that we are interested in calculating the probability that, under these conditions, the first student has given exactly $5$ correct answers. To count the number of "valid" distributions, we can firstly note that these $5$ correct answers can be distributed, among the $6$ answers given by the first student, in $\binom{6}{5}=6$ ways. Then, we have to multiply by the number of ways in which the remaining $2$ correct answers can be distributed among the $4$ answers given by the second student, that is to say $\binom{4}{2}=6$. So, we have $6 \cdot 6=36$ valid distributions  in which the first student has given exactly $5$ correct answers. Dividing this by the total number of distributions given by our sample space leads to a probability of $36/120=0.3$.

Lastly, we could have obtained the same result by dividing the probabilities of valid and total distributions, instead of their numbers. In this case, for any given value of $p$, we would have obtained $[36\, p^7 \, (1-p)^3]/[120 \, p^7 \, (1-p)^3]$, which again reduces to $0.3$.

Answer (score 2):

Conflating the symbols $A$ and $B$ with the random variables representing their number of correct answers.

Perhaps to start...
$$
\mathbb{P}(A = d \mid A+B = c) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A = d, A+B = c)}{\mathbb{P}(A+B = c)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A = d, B = c-d)}{\mathbb{P}(A+B = c)} = \cdots
$$

Comment: This is a great answer! Can you please add a little more explanation about how you got these steps?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut The first equality uses the definition of conditional expectation, the second follows since the event $\{A = d, A+B = c\}$ is the same event as $\{A = d, B = c-d\}$.

Comment: @Tom so would the denominator give c*p? and the numerator would simplify to P(A=d)?

Comment: @FelicioGrande: I don't think so. For the denominator $A+B$ is the sum of binomial random variables (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176385/sum-of-two-independent-binomial-variables). For the numerator, since $A$ and $B$ are independent, it should simplify to $\mathbb{P}(A = d)\,\mathbb{P}(B = c-d)$.

Comment: what would P(A=d) give? (cCd)?

Comment: and I'm confused by what the denominator would simplify too as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Since a correctly answered question has independently an certain probability of having been answered by $A$ rather than $B$ *( Why?  What probability? )*, then what is the distribution for the count of correct questions answered by $A$ when given that $d$ questions were answered correctly in total?

Comment: i think it would be a binomial distribution

Comment: @Felicio Correct.  With what parameters?

Comment: P(A=d | B=c-d)?

Comment: @Felicio What are the parameters of the binomial distribution of $A$ given $A+B=c$ . What are the $n,p$ in $[A\mid (A+B=c)]\sim\mathcal {Bin}(n, p)$.$$\mathsf P(A=d\mid A+B=c) ~=~ \binom{\color{green}n}{d} \color{green}p^d (1-\color{green}p)^{\color{green}n-d}$$

Comment: im not sure, could you explain?

Comment: I tried to solve this, and I got

Comment: (aCd) * (bC(c-d)) * p^(c-d) * (1-p)^(d-c) / ((a+b)Cd)

Comment: @FelicioGrande Where are $a$ and $b$ coming from?  Don't add variables from nowhere.

Comment: @FelicioGrande What is the *number of trials*, if the trials are the correctly answered questions?  What is the *success rate* of the correctly answered question if a success is that the question was answered by $A$ rather than $B$?  Those are the parameters of the Binomial Distribution that plug into the formula.

Comment: sorry a are the questions that A answered and b are the questions that B answered, it's a bit clearer in the question itself.

Comment: the number of trails would be c, and the success rate of that would be p?

Comment: No, $p$ is the rate at which $A$ and $B$ both answer questions correctly.  What is the rate that the correctly-answered questions are answered by $A$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46327/discussion-between-felicio-grande-and-graham-kemp).