# Finding the exact value of $P(X \leq np)$ for $k = 10$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1,......,X_k$ be iid random variables from a Binomial distribution with n=4 and p=0.1.

Let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$.
Find the exact value of P($\bar{X}$ $\leq np)$ for $k = 10$.

I have found out the value of this problem using the central limit theorem (CLT) using randomly generated values but this problem specifically states to not use CLT. At first, I thought to write it like this:
$$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k P(X_i \leq np),$$
but I am not sure this is allowed.

Is this problem only possible if we randomly generated $X_1$ to $X_k$ random variables with $\operatorname{Bin}(4,0.1)$?

Comment: Maybe consider that $(k\overline X)\sim Bin(kn, p)$, and also $P(\overline X \le np) = P(k\overline X\le knp)$. For the exact value there are a few probabilities to add.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the sum of independent random variables $$S = \sum_{i = 1}^k X_i = k\overline X.$$

Then [$S$ also follows binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176385): $S \sim Bin(kn, p) = Bin(40, 0.1)$. The required probability is

$$\begin{align*}
P(\overline X \le np) &= P(k\overline X \le knp)\\
&= P(S \le 4)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^4 \binom{40}{i}0.1^i(1-0.1)^{40-i}\\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$